# What do the stats in The Club represent?

Tags: the-club

In The Club, characters have three stats:

- Speed
- Strength
- Stamina

What do these mean in gameplay? Speed is obviously how fast the character runs, but the other two aren't so clear. [GameFAQs doesn't seem to know either.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932916-the-club/41955739)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are pretty obvious. Strength is pretty much what it means in the dictionary, **but** only for melee attacks, **ONLY**. Stamia is practically the energy power for sprinting and special attacks. This is all that strength and stamia does.

Comment: I'm actually finding it difficult to check the strength. Enemies die with one hit, regardless of strength.

Answer (score 1):

I think its pretty straight-forward. strength means the power the character has that usually means how much damage you cause when you do a melee attack. stamina means how long you can sprint, or run faster.

Comment: Power attacks? Are those different from melee attacks?